# Adding CHECK constraint Syntax

Tags: sql

I keep getting a syntax error even though I reviewed different formats that the CHECK constraint can be in. What am I doing wrong?

```
ALTER TABLE `eventsdataview`
ADD PitchArea CHAR(10) DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN' NOT NULL, CHECK (PitchArea IN ('Area1', 'Area2', 'Area3', 'Area4'));
ALTER TABLE `trackdataview`
ADD PitchArea CHAR(10) DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN' NOT NULL, CHECK (PitchArea IN ('Area1', 'Area2', 'Area3', 'Area4'));
```

Comment: What database are you using?  The backticks suggest MySQL.  If so, check constraints are not actually checked, so you can just drop them from the query.

Comment: `DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN' NOT NULL` looks a bit odd, as in ANSI/iSO SQL specs `NULL` actually means "unknown"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax drops the comma, because you are trying to express an in-line constraint.  So:

```
ALTER TABLE `eventsdataview`
    ADD PitchArea CHAR(10) DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN' NOT NULL
         CHECK (PitchArea IN ('Area1', 'Area2', 'Area3', 'Area4'));
```

As I mention in a comment, MySQL only very recently added support check constraints, so this may be for information purposes only.  If you want to validate the values, use an `enum` or foreign key.

Comment: MySQL 8.0.16 finally added support for check constraints

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I was hoping it would go into MySQL 8 from the get-go, so I wouldn't have to try to remember arcane versioning.

Comment: Yes, MySQL's policy to introduce new features with minor (patch) releases is really confusing.

Comment: *"MySQL 8.0.16 finally added support for check constraints"* @a_horse_with_no_name already "supported" CHECK for much longer but not in `CREATE TABLE`, you would need a create a updateble [VIEW with check option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-check-option.html)..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: that's not a check constraint. The `with check` option only ensures that only the rows that the view returns can also be updated or deleted. That is something completely different

Comment: *"that's not a check constraint."* i know @a_horse_with_no_name i did wrote "supported" for a reason as that method can be considered as a possible workaround to emulate check constraint. on the table on lower MySQL versions.. *"That is something completely different "* Yes you have to read a bit between the lines here.. INSERT / UPDATE on the view with check option and DELETE / SELECT on the normal table, it is not ideal but it works ..